# Unable to create curves in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, line-art

I am new to Adobe Indesign, and I am currently using the 2019 version.
So, I want to create a text on a curve line like this.

[image: Curved Text]

**The Methodology I used**
I tried to create this line by using 2 anchor points and then using the **Convert Point Direction Tool** on of the anchors of line. It showed the curve as I was holding the tool, but as soon as I left the tool the line didn't change.

[image: My version]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, and how can I create better curves in Indesign.

Comment: Your steps are correct. There's no telling why it isn't working. It should.

Comment: Could it be a bug?

Comment: Well, I'd try simply restarting InDesign before anything.

Comment: I restarted my Indesign but still, it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried doing what you described with the 2019 version and creating the curve works for me. Have you tried resetting the InDesign preferences by pressing Shift+Ctrl+Alt(Win) / Shift+Option+Command+Control(Mac) while clicking the InDesign icon to open it? Just be aware that this will reset some InDesign settings to what it was like when you downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Type on a Path tool, located in the little submenu under the T? I have CS6 and that is where my Type on a Path tool is.

I've done this many, many times and generally the way I do it is to draw my curve first, then select the Type on a Path tool and type my copy in. From there, you can change the font, size, etc. and with the direct selection tool (white arrow) you can adjust the handles on your curve to your liking.

Another way I've done this is to draw an oval, type in my copy with the Type on a Path tool, and then adjust the type. When you do it this way, the type probably won't end up where you want it, so you will need to drag the vertical lines when you hover over your path with your black arrow tool. Sometimes this is easier, because you are able to make the curve uniform on both sides. As long as you don't use a color on the stroke, it won't matter whether the rest of the oval is there. Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bug, but if you are a beginner it is more likely you jumbled something up here.

Hard to say without looking at the file, but this looks to me like 2 objects on top of each others. Each of those objects are rectangles, with a near zero height. One of those rectangles has got a curve set on one corner. And the other one is selected. (See reproduction below)
[image]

I would recommend to delete these objects and start over.

Draw a line with the `pen` or `line` tool. <sub>(Pen tool can make curves when mouse pressed during moving.)</sub>

[image]

Then use the `Convert Direction Point Tool` to make it curved. <sub>(left click on pen icon)</sub>

[image]

If you select the `Type on Path` tool it will write the text along the line.

<sup>(If you click on this line with the `Type` tool it will wrap the text within the shape.)</sup>

[image]

(After this double-click the type on path icon for more alignment options)

[image]